# Can I make all API request from the server side in angular universal?

Tags: angular, backend, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

I added angular universal to my angular project and I want to now ensure that all post and get API requests are done from the server side and not the client side. Is it possible to achieve this in Angular?

For Instance, I have a form for posting data to the backend. When the user submits the form, do I want the post request to be done from the backend and not from the client side?

I want this request to be made from the backend.

```
onSubmit(){
    this.http.post('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts', this.testForm.value)
    .subscribe(res=>{
     //Some response 
    })
  }
```

Comment: Not always. On your laptop on IISExpress you can. But for me, on my live server it's not possible

Answer (score 0):

Angular Universal is not meant to do HTTP request once the client side has loaded or make HTTP requests besides GET for hydrating the view.

You can make an HTTP GET request to fetch data and then transfer the state to the client side. However, per user authorization and authentication with cookies or such won't work on the server side.

Every other requests that happen after the bootstraping of the application are and should be done from the client side.